# CLISP ext:run-program

Tags: command-line-arguments, external, clisp

I am having trouble using run-program with arguments. The documentation at http://www.clisp.org/impnotes/shell.html is very incomplete for a newbie like me, and I would need to see some examples.

In particular, how can I get the directory list of files with "txt" extension?

This works:

```
(ext:run-program "ls" ) ; I am running on Mac OS X
```

but if I add arguments, it doesn't work. I have tried:

```
(ext:run-program "ls" :arguments "*.txt")
(ext:run-program "ls" :arguments '(*.txt))
(ext:run-program "ls *.txt)
```

Can anyone tell me the right syntax and, hopefully, provide some more examples of `run-program`?

Note that the above is just an example. What I want is to be able to use run-command, not to list the directory, which I can do with list-directory.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

### List Files

First of all, if all you want is to list files, you can use the standard
[`directory`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_dir.htm)
or CLISP-specific [`ext:dir`](http://clisp.org/impnotes/dir-func.html#dir).

### Globbing

Second, the `"*"` globbing is expanded by *shell*, not individual commands, so you need to use
[`ext:run-shell-command`](http://www.clisp.org/impnotes/shell.html#run-prog)
instead of `ext:run-program`:

```
> (ext:run-shell-command "ls *.txt")
foo.txt

> (ext:run-program "ls" :arguments '("foo.txt"))
foo.txt

> (ext:run-program "ls")
foo.txt
bar.c
```

### Summary

The manual assumes a certain level of familiarity with the way modern OSes work in this respect. The other excellent answer addresses those issues in detail; briefly:

- `run-program` executes another program using the standard `fork`/`exec` paradigm
- `run-shell-command` goes through shell, so you can use globbing and things like loops
- `shell` is mostly for interactive use

### More examples

You can find more example of `run-program` in the [CLISP test suite](https://sourceforge.net/p/clisp/clisp/ci/default/tree/modules/syscalls/test.tst).

If you want to read from a compressed file, you can do [this](http://www.clisp.org/impnotes/shell.html#pipe):

```
;; return lines as a list
(with-input-from-file (in (ext:make-pipe-input-stream "gunzip -c myfile.gz"))
  (loop for l = (read-line in nil nil)
    while l
    collect l))
```

Actually, you can [use CLISP as your shell](http://www.clisp.org/clash.html)!

Comment: Thanks very much! That works. Do you know where I can find a more thorough description of run-program, run-shell-command and shell, with examples? When to use which? TIA

Comment: yw. not that I know of. let's turn this question into one: what do you want to do?

Comment: I want to learn how to interact with other apps, executing programs, and exchanging data between them and CLISP. One example I have now in my hands is how to unzip a file, wait until it is decompressed, and read it. I think that the explanations you´ve given me are very useful, but a little bit too complex for a beginner like me, so perhaps some detailed documentation would be very useful for a lot of people.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
(ext:run-program "stat" :arguments '("/tmp" "/sys"))
```

<sup>I am using `stat`, not `ls` in this example.</sup>

What you might want is [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29) (read [glob(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html)). You should do it yourself in Lisp, or else run `/bin/sh -c`; in other words it is up to you to build the *expanded* list passed after `:arguments`. (You can't pass `*.txt` as a single argument, it would have the same effect as a quoted shell argument like in 
 `ls '*.txt'` shell command)

This is not CLISP specific. `ext:run-program` is probably [forking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28system_call%29) then calling (in the child) [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) so you have to do the globbing yourself.

Maybe you want the CLISP equivalent of [glob(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/glob.3.html) or [fnmatch(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fnmatch.3.html). I don't know enough CLISP if it has them or not.

Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) to get a more clear picture of this. On [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) systems the invoking process (often your shell when typing a command, or your Common Lisp program if using `ext:run-program` ....) has to expand and build the argument list. The point is that when you run `ls *.txt` it is your shell (not the `ls` process) which is expanding `*.txt`, so `ls`  is getting an *expanded* argument list like e.g. `a.txt foo.txt bar.txt`; so you need to do the same in your Lisp code.